# Избежать коллизии файлов при загрузки на сервер (PHP)

Tags: php, файлы, загрузка

Доброго всем.
Вопрос про коллизии файлов при загрузки через foreach.

```
foreach ($_FILES['user_file']['error'] as $key => $error)
```

Скрипт работает, всё загружается\выгружается. (в каталог для файлов)
Ссылки на файлы пишутся в БД.
Вот только поинтересоваться хочу, как сделать, чтобы юзеры могли закидывать файлы с одинаковыми именами, а те, чтобы каким-то образом не перезаписывались (как к примеру в ОС Windows - используют принцип постфикса "-копия(2)").
Я так думаю, тоже каждому файлу просто давать индекс к имени и записывать в БД. Например name_xxx.doc (где "name" - это имя, а "_xxx" - индекс), хотя с префикс поставить программно легче, чем перед расширением постфикс.
Или есть уже "велосипед" на эту тему?

Comment: Насколько важно сохранять оригинальное имя/часть его?

Comment: Да не так что-бы очень важно. Пока в программе 40 человек.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Реализовал так (без времени) - простейший пока вариант (зато симпатичная каталогизация на сервере, а не куча файлов в одном каталоге). Теперь в системе будет работать один человек. Если потребуется, можно будет приписать время к файлу префиксом.

```
mkdir("files/".date("m_d_y"), 0777);
$uploaddir = "files/".date("m_d_y")."/";
//получается [server]:\files\09_06_23\
```

Comment: а как потом искать этот файл?

Answer (score 2):

Я делаю md5 от содержимого. Даже если зальют одинаковые картинки и одна затрется - другая все равно останется. Только при удалении надо смотреть, чтобы больше на картинку ссылок не оставалось.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае достаточно посчитать хэш от имени плюс что-то случайное (генерить до достижения уникальности). Если файлов много, то раскидывать их по каталогам, где, например, имя каталога первого уровня - первый символ хэша и т.д. Например, хэш от имени файла: `1234567890`. Значит, складываем его в:

```
./data
./data/1/
./data/1/2/
 34567890.docx
```

А можно вообще не париться. Раз уж используется БД, то именем файла может быть primary key из неё...

Answer (score 1):

**Если сохранять оригинальные имена нужно:**
я создавал бы на каждого пользователя директорию (название директории может быть равным id пользователя в базе) и сохранял бы загруженные файлы в его директорию. При загрузке файла с таким же именем можно говорить, что файл с таким именем уже загружался и спрашивать разрешение сделать постфикс/ввести новое имя и т.д.

**Если сохранять оригинальные имена не нужно:**

- хэш файла
- дописать время загрузки в начало/конец/средину имени
- просто сгенерировать рандомную строку для имени файла

Так же нужно помнить, что в имени загружаемого файла может быть что угодно и надо бы имя это проверить и вырезать из него все, что может нанести вред (кавычки, слэши и т.д.).

Comment: Про рандом интересная идея,

Comment: Я думаю, что можно рандомить имя, далее складировать файлы, в имя ссылкы записывать имя принимаемого файла, а в таргет - рандомное.  
Хотя при скачивании файла юзером, нормального имени файлу уже не будет возможности дать.

Comment: @I_CaR, если нужно имя такое, каким его загрузил пользователь - делайте варианты с директориями (мой или @klopp).  
или можно придумать что-нибудь свое для именования более-менее случайное. например, sitename_<random_str>_<unixtimestamp>

Answer (score 1):

Может помочь ф-я PHP [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.tempnam.php) – создаст файл с уникальным именем, точно никого не перезаписав, и «забронировав» это имя (создав пустой файл). А в БД вы можете сохранить под уникальным ID оригинальное имя загруженного файла.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно просто к имени файла дописывать время в формате unixtime в секундах или в миллисекундах. Вероятность коллизии (того, что в одну миллисекунду пользователь загрузит файл с одним и тем же именем) крайне мала. А чтобы ее исключить в принципе, то можно дописать id/логин пользователя.

Например:

```
$name = "filename".time();
```

или

```
$name = "filename".round(microtime(1) * 1000);
```

Также, для дополнительной подстраховки, ограничьте минимальную длину имени файла. Т.е. чтобы имя файла не было короче, например, десяти символов.

Comment: Данный ход был сразу мной продуман. Но он переписывает расширение файла. Файл становится нечитабельным для ПО пользователя.
Т.е. тут нужно добавлять префикс, как я и описал в задаче.